# Solidity function expects interface but address was passed as parameter

Tags: solidity, hardhat, defi

I'm following the Superfluid tutorial (please see complete repo [here](https://github.com/superfluid-finance/super-examples/blob/main/projects/money-streaming-intro/contracts/MoneyRouter.sol)) and I have a question regarding interfaces as function parameters.
I tested both the contract and the script and they work fine.

From the aforementioned reference:

```
function sendLumpSumIntoContract(ISuperToken token, uint256 amount) external 
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
```

Now, when I call the function *sendLumpSumIntoContract*, I pass in the **address of the token instead of the ISuperToken interface**:

```
await moneyRouter.connect(signers[0]).sendLumpSumIntoContract(daix.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("500")).then(function (tx) {
    console.log(`Tx Hash: ${tx.hash}`)
    });
```

I expected an interface to be built and to be passed as parameter. Explanations as to why this is not the case are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface just provides the information of what can be done with this object?, if it is ISuperToken solidity knows that any address parse as that interface can call the methods described by the interface, in this case `transferFrom` , when you pass the address what the code does is to say, this address is corresponding to a deployment of the interface I just cast it as, in your case `ISuperToken` .

If you provide the wrong interface, it doesnt matter is you pass the correct address you wont be able to call methods in the contract address since they are not in the interface you are referring to in your code.

Short answer: When you pass the address solidity treats that address as a deployed instance of the interface.

Comment: Thanks! And what happens if a contract needs to be passed in as parameter? Is this behavior also true?

Comment: Interesting comment from @ziad - The interface you use as the type in your Solidity code will be used to figure out how to call the functions on the contract, so the only thing left to know is the address of said contract. See https://morten.dev/posts/why-do-we-need-transaction-data

Comment: Yes contracts follow the same logic, you always pass the address